# Resize Windows window and redraw the contents at the same time in C

Tags: c, windows, winapi, window, gdi

I have some code which expands my Windows app window in all four directions as an animation on startup. I then need to re-center some elements in order for it to look correctly. It looks somewhat like this:

```
//... Logic for new window size and position

bool success = SetWindowPos(window, NULL, xpos, ypos, new_window_width, new_window_height, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOCOPYBITS);
if(!success)
    printf("Failed resizing window in window_on_create. Error code: %lu\n", GetLastError());

RECT rect = {0, 0, new_window_width, new_window_height};
InvalidateRect(window, &rect, true);
```

In my paint code, the elements are automatically centered using the current window width and height. My problem is that there is a slight delay between the resizing and the repainting, which causes the elements on screen to jitter when the window is being resized. It happens even when I am only drawing a single PNG image to the window. Is there a way to perhaps resize my window, redraw the elements and THEN show the result on screen?

Comment: Are you looking for [`DeferWindowPos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-deferwindowpos)?

Comment: @IInspectable That sadly has the same effect. The window is moved and resized first, and then redrawn.

Comment: Just a guess... Does adding `SWP_NOREDRAW` help?

Comment: "*In my paint code, the elements are automatically centered using the current window width and height.*" - you are not positioning UI CONTROLS while painting, are you?

Comment: @AndreasSandberg Assign `CS_HREDRAW` and `CS_VREDRAW` to window class styles in `WNDCLASSEX`. Please check the doc and sample:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-class-styles.

Comment: GDI is not built for flicker-free resizing. `SWP_NOREDRAW`, then use `WM_PRINTCLIENT` to render the window to a memory DC and blit it to the display.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I don't think this is accurate anymore. With desktop composition, all rendering goes to off-screen surfaces, and you'd have to try *really* hard to introduce flicker. As I understand the question, it's not about flicker; it is about jitter caused by repeatedly rendering to coordinates, that are just a few pixels apart.

Comment: @AndreasSandberg Is that good? Does it meet your requirement?

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT From what I can see, it doesn't change the result in any noticeable way. There still is a delay between the resize and redraw, causing the last frame to be display for a fraction of a second.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes exactly, it is not about issues about statically drawn images. The problem is that I am changing the position of the window while trying to keep the elements centered on the screen. However, before the elements can be redrawn centered, the last frame is still shown for a fraction of a second, and so when the window is resized multiple times it creates a flickering/ghosting effect, which is really painful for the eyes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau No, I am only repositioning a single image to the center of my window and then repainting the window.

Comment: @AndreasSandberg Have you tried the `SWP_NOREDRAW` by Craig Estey said? Redrawing, resize and repositioning are asynchronous, maybe adding `Sleep()` between them may solve the flickering problem, but at the expense of the rate of response.  You can provide a minimal reproducible example, with which the community can provide more solutions.

Comment: The issue will be far easier to understand if you can provide a bare-bones [mcve] (it could render a rectangle in place of the PNG image, for example). @Torrecto-MSFT **Anything** in USER32 is strictly synchronous. Adding a call to `Sleep` will do no more than slow things down.